# What's the word for having a very long scrotum?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've forgotten the word for having a very long scrotum, it's like rapscallion or scallywag but I just can't remember.

I've searched but the majority of references are medical conditions and it's not a medical term I'm looking for.

I'm hoping someone just knows the answer.

Thanks.

I'm not looking for swollen testicles, it's a word that means you have a very long scrotum - like an old man. If you've seen the movie Bad Grandpa with Johnny Knoxville, the part where he does a strip in a bar on ladies night and his scrotum hangs out of his underpants, that's the look I'm thinking of.

It's just one word and I'm sure it has the letters 'all' in it like the two words above (not like ball).

(I keep wanting to say "It's on the tip of my tongue" but that's just wrong)

Comment: not scallywag i don't think

Comment: saggy baggy ?..

Comment: The closest medical term is probably [macroorchidism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroorchidism) (having abnormally large testes) - but for a slang term, @ermanen is probably on the right track with some jokey allusion to ***bags***, - or perhaps ***applesacks***.

Comment: There are several medical terms for physiological or pathological conditions, @FumbleFingers, but macroorchidism (to the point of being visually detectable) is a rarity. Physiological conditions would include "old age scrotum", and the most common pathological conditions would be hydrocele and varicocele.  Then again, that's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not a medical term, it definitely has 'all' in it which is why I gave the two words it sounds like. I'll edit the question to add more information.

Comment: Well, one might attempt *well-bestrutted*, but I doubt whether that’s what you were thinking of.

Comment: @tchrist No, not well-bestrutted. Not swollen, just hanging loosely.

Comment: _Scallops(slang)_?

Comment: Perhaps **Scrotesque**?

Comment: @andy256 Scrotesque is a brilliant word, not the right one but brilliant anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be thinking of *rantallion*, which sounds similar to your suggestion of rapscallion.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rantallion) defines rantallion as a person whose scrotum is longer than his penis:

> A person whose penis is insufficiently long, in its 'relaxed' mode, to exceed the length of the scrotum

Comment: Erm is that not usual?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the word you're after is **rantallion:**

> *n.* - one whose scrotum is longer than his penis   (http://www.kokogiak.com/logolepsy/ow_r.html#rantallion)
>
> (plural *rantallions)* (slang) (ca. 1780-1850): A person whose penis is insufficiently long, in its 'relaxed' mode, to exceed the length of the scrotum
> (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rantallion)
>
> Grose’s Dictionary: “one whose scrotum is so relaxed as to be longer than his penis, i.e. whose shot pouch is longer than the barrel of his piece.”
> (http://wordcraft.infopop.cc/dictionary/part9.htm#rantallion)

Comment: nice work Erik..

Comment: Thanks @JoeBlow - However, for all that I found those references, I'm not convinced that the word is anything but a mildly amusing curiosity; perhaps one that you might employ when composing a studied insult. :)

Comment: Right - I've just realised they're pretty jokey dictionaries eh.  There's a fine line between a word like (snicker) "merkin" which is probably fair to say is "completely real, a bit obscure, but produces snickers" and, well, a made up jokey word.  I guess I don't know. Although it's a jokey QA it raises deep questions about what the hell a 'real' word is. These guys suggest wordsense.eu/rantallion/ it was slang from 1800. But what is "wordsense.eu"? WTF do they know? Who are they? It's tough.